# WPF - Program crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, crash

WPF application I wrote runs fine on my PC but on my friend's (same as mine Win 7 x64) it crashes. I tried to compile it either to x86 or x64 but problem still persists. I also sent him test app with simple button and message to see if it's lack of .net framework problem but it runs with no problems. My app uses MSSQL and on WPF part binding and various templates which were not included in test case. What is wrong with it?

I include error report(sorry for possibly bad translation it was in different language):

```
Problem signature:
Problem event name:     CLR20r3
Problem signature: 01:  surfmanagertake2.exe
Problem signature: 02:  1.0.0.0
Problem signature: 03:  53b3b026
Problem signature: 04:  PresentationFramework
Problem signature: 05:  4.0.30319.18408
Problem signature: 06:  52312f13
Problem signature: 07:  7fe8
Problem signature: 08:  ee
Problem signature: 09:  System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
Operating system version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
Regional settings ID:   1045
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: How do you deploy it? Are you sure all files are deployed, including configuration etc.? Did you check logs?

Comment: Can your friend connect to the MSSQL database? Is the problem reproduced if you turn off the database and try to run the software on your local machine

Comment: I deployed everything - I ran it in my PC sent zipped to my friend's but it crashed. No, he did't sent them and he left several minutes ago. That's all i have.

Comment: Did you perform the test is asked you to do?

Comment: Problem arises before application tries to connect to database - I included MessageBox at beginning (before windows initialization or setting database connection) but even MessageBox doesn't launch. @karl-henrik i turned off database but even so MessageBox still appeared.

Comment: Check his windows eventlog to see if that gives any clue

Comment: @karl-henrik He is in another town, with no clue about logs so it could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar problems before, where the app works perfectly fine on some machines and crashes\slow on others which appear to be the same physical\OS spec.

I tracked down the issue to differing versions of core assemblies used by WPF - PresentationCore.dll, PresentationFramework.dll etc.

The easiest way to see all the managed references (.Net assemblies) a process is using a tool like Process Explorer or ProcDump (both from sysinternals).

These should allow you to take a full dump which can then be openned in Visual Studio and show a list of the loaded assemblies and their versions. If the version numbers of the core WPF assemblies are different then I suggest one of the machines has a Hotfix the other doesn't.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2009/12/30/what-is-a-dump-and-how-do-i-create-one.aspx